# How to create an array of string spliting a char that have words separated by a " "? c++

Tags: c++, mobile, marmalade

The only question i found that tried to help me was this one [C++: splitting a string into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029324/c-splitting-string-into-array).
I'm new to c++ and i need to have an array of string that cointain each of these words that i have in this char.

Here is the code:

```
s3eFile* file = s3eFileOpen("chatTest/restrict_words.txt","rb"); 
        int len = s3eFileGetSize(file);

        char* temp = new char[len];
        if (file!=NULL)
        {
            s3eFileRead(temp,len,1, file);
            s3eFileClose(file);
        }
```

So i need to make this temp to turn in to an array so i can work with it?
There's a way?

Comment: Since you are using new, why don't use a vector instead of a plain array?

Comment: vector<string>? i guess its ok i just need to know how to do it

Comment: Use `std::string::find` or one of its relatives.  Also see `std::string::substr`.

Comment: Note: `char *temp` is equivalent to `char temp[]` when you're working with it.  If you just want to grab index 3 it's `char c = temp[3];`.  Just watch the null terminators when using `C` constructs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a c++ code then i would recommend moving to std::string instead of char* and use powerful std tools like fstream, stringstream etc . The link which you have specified gives detailed answer on how to do it

```
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;
    .
    .
    .
    s3eFile* file = s3eFileOpen("chatTest/restrict_words.txt","rb"); 
    int len = s3eFileGetSize(file);

    char* temp = new char[len];
    if (file!=NULL)
    {
        s3eFileRead(temp,len,1, file);

        //Adding Code here
        string str(temp);
        stringstream sstr(str)
        vector<string> str_array;
        string extracted;
        while(sstr.good()){
         sstr>>extracted;
         str_array.push_back(extracted);
        }
        //at this point all the strings are in the array str_array

        s3eFileClose(file);
    }
```

you can access the strings using iterator or by simple indexing like arrays `str_array[i]`

Comment: How do i clean that char* temp after i use it?

Comment: i can do the same thing with the s3eFile* file right?

Comment: Well, I don't know about s3eFileOpen and s3eFileClose function. One would have to look at its documentation/implementation to know for sure whether to free/delete the memory or not.

Comment: @Ravi If open allocates, I'd expect close to delete.  But you definitely never know with 3rdparty offshoots.

Answer (score 3):

maybe something like:

```
ifstream f("chatTest/restrict_words.txt");

vector<string> vec;

while (!f.fail())
{
  string word;
  f >> word; 
  vec.push_back(move(word));
}
```

Comment: Wow `move()`.  Is that really important enough to be introduced at this level?  I wish it were already automatic for `.push_back()`...