# Store a string into an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, iostream

I have a string variable

string = " this is my string"

I want to store every word separated by a **whitespace** into an array

- array[0]="this";
- array[1]="is";
- array[2]="my";
- array[3]="string";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Comment: Maybe this post can be useful: [Split a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/6032132)

Comment: Can you confirm that the initial leading space in your string is deliberate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: splitting a string into an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029324/c-splitting-a-string-into-an-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/basic_stringstream) and [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter):

```
vector<string> v;
istringstream ss(" this is my string");
copy(istream_iterator<string>(ss), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(v));
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/RQMD81505)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to include "sstream" class like:

```
#include <sstream>
```

Then use below code:

```
    string str= "this is my string"
    int len = str.length();
    string arr[len];
    int i = 0;
    stringstream ssin(str);
    while (ssin.good() && i < len){
        ssin >> arr[i];
        ++i;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you can use string delimiter concept

```
 strtok(const char * str, int delimiter);
```

for your case, delimiter is "white space".

program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main ()
 {
     char str[] ="This a sample string";
     char * output_after_delimiter_applied;
     char *out_arr[4];
     int i=0;

     printf("The original string is %s\n", str);

     output_after_delimiter_applied = strtok (str," ");

     while (output_after_delimiter_applied != NULL)
     {
         out_arr[i] = output_after_delimiter_applied;
         output_after_delimiter_applied = strtok (NULL, " ");    
                   // NULL parameter is for continuing the search
                  //  delimiter is "white space".
         i++;
     }

     for(i=0; i < 4 ; i++)
         printf("%s\n", out_arr[i]); 

     return 0;
  }
```

we can add any no. of delimiters with in double quotes. it is like string (delimiter) search.