# Splitting a string up into individual words and placing them in a vector

Tags: c++

I want to be able to place each individual word of the string of any size into a vector. This is what I have so far:

```
vector <string> broken;
while(choice != " "){
    int space = choice.find(" ")-1;
    string word = choice.substr(0,space);
    broken.push_back(word);
    choice = choice.substr(space+1);``
    cout << choice;
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into `std::istringstream`. You can use it do do stuff like `while (stream >> word) broken.push_back (word);` Hard to get much easier.

Comment: Similar question is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16029324/c-splitting-a-string-into-an-array Updated it using vector::push_back instead of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use stringstream, you can insert the multiword string in the stringstream then make a while loop inserting from the stringstream to another string, then you'll have each word separated in each iteration of the loop.

```
stringstream ss;
ss << choice;
vector <string> broken;

string word;
while(ss >> word){
    broken.push_back(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using an `istringstream` :

```
istringstream iss(choice);
vector<string> broken{istream_iterator<string>{iss},
                      istream_iterator<string>{}};
```

You'll need to `#include <sstream>` and `#include <iterator>`.